# Can I skip certificate verification oracle utl_http?

Tags: oracle, curl, plsql

I'm developing some apps in pl/SQL which connect to multiple external services,

Example:

```
declare
 utl_req         utl_http.req;
 utl_resp        utl_http.resp;
begin
-- This line in production for security, but takes forever to get authorized 
-- by oracle host provider :@
-- utl_http.set_wallet('file:/path/wallet', 'password');

-- In test env i would like something like
-- utl_http.set_option('CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST', false);
-- utl_http.set_option('CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER', false);
 utl_req := utl_http.begin_request('https://login.microsoftonline.com/...
/oauth2/token', 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');-- Die
--...more code
end;
```

Output:

```
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure
```

Is there a way to order Oracle to ignore certificate validation for testing purposes, no auth waiting to add cert to wallet.

Something like in php

```
$curl_request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/...
/oauth2/token');
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    // No thankyou i don't care about security in testing :P
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    ... more code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found a way to do this, what I've done is build a simple PHP middle man app that can be accessed with SSL and pipe my request through that.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly how we are doing it now we pipe the requests through a server of our own control in which we can install as many certificates without waiting anyone authorization.

Answer (score 5):

No, certificate verification can not be skipped for `utl_http.begin_request` through command line options. For this aim, creating an `Oracle Wallet` is needed. [Oracle Wallet Manager GUI Tool](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_wallet_manager.htm)  can be used to create it.

After creating two certificate files `ewallet.p12` and `cwallet.sso`, move them to the wallet folders in your OS, and change the *file permissions* to *770*.

Just before `utl_http.begin_request` line issue

```
utl_http.set_wallet('file:/etc/oracle/owm');
```

to point to the *OS wallet path*.

Comment: That's just sad, I appreciate your answer. I know that you need a wallet and how to configure it, but we have no access to do that ourselves in the server where our oracle instances are, so we need to ask the provider to configure those things (adding certs, static files for apex, css, js) through tickets, and this sometimes takes forever(weeks even months) and with a lot of scrutiny and justification required, it's ok for production but for development is a hassle was hoping plsql was more dynamic(ha!) and had an option so skip this most languages has such options even plain CURL.